# Best practice for using callbacks with structs?

Tags: ios, swift, struct, callback

I want to use a callback on a struct which fails with the error **'Closure cannot implicitly capture a mutating self parameter'** on the line `self.pictures = catPictures`

How I understand it that has something to do with structs are value types and a closure holding a copy of it isn't really safe.

The usage is similar to the following:

```
final class APIService {

    static func loadFunnyCatPicturesAsync(completion: @escaping ([UIImage]) -> () ) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            // Do a lot of fancy stuff here

            let decodedImages = [UIImage()]

            // DispatchQueue.main.async or .sync? - I'm not sure about that :|
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(decodedImages)
            }
        }
    }

}

struct viewModel {

    var pictures: [UIImage] {
        didSet {
            // Do synchronous stuff here again
        }
    }

    mutating func loadPicture() {
        APIService.loadCatPicturesAsync { (catPictures) in
            self.pictures = catPictures
        }
    }

}
```

.

So should I just make the `viewModel` a class or is there a nice way to make this work with structs.

And when I make the callback should I use `DispatchQueue.main.async` or `.sync`

Note: I don't really want to use the delegate pattern, because I think it adds too much overhead.

Comment: `loadPicture` is not legit. You cannot mutate `self` in an asynchronous callback. Use a class instead, or find another pattern.